# Concatenation beginner level

Tags: python

Problem:

Give the first proper noun: Milk

Give the second proper noun: float

The words together form: Milkfloat

```
noun1 = input("Give the first proper noun: ")
noun2 = input("Give the second proper noun: ")
print("The words together form: "='noun1'+'noun2')
```

**"='noun1'+'noun2'** This doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `print (f"The words together form: {noun1}{noun2}")`

Comment: print("The words together form: ="+ noun1+noun2)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please remember, SO is not to solve your assignments. You have to atleast reframe your question so that it looks like you are asking a doubt.

Comment: print("The words together form: " + noun1 + noun2 )

Answer (score 0):

this should work if you are looking for concatenating the nouns

```
noun1 = input("Give the first proper noun: ")
noun2 = input("Give the second proper noun: ")
print("The words together form: = "+noun1+noun2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
noun1 = input("Give the first proper noun: ")
noun2 = input("Give the second proper noun: ")
print("The words together form: "='noun1'+'noun2')
```

noun1 and noun2 are variables here and you are printing then in '' quotes. They should be without quotes. Find below third print line.

```
print("The words together form: "+noun1+noun2)
```